# application stops when using timer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

I am trying to randomly draw two rectangles on screen using onDraw method, and I want to clear the screen and make two new rectangles every 2 seconds. So I wrapped invalidate() within a Timer. However, when I run this code, it shows me two rectangles at first, and stopped running after 2 seconds. I am guessing there is something wrong with my Timer, since my code worked well before I add the Timer. 
Why is this not working, and how should I fix it so that it draws 2 rectangles every 2 seconds(with previous rectangles removed)?
Thanks in advance.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);   
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();
    int rectangleWidth = width / 5;//Width of a rectangle
    int rectangleHeight = height / 15; //height of a rectangle
    for(int i = 0; i< 2; i++) {
        randomLeft = randomGenerator1.nextInt(width - rectangleWidth);
        colors = new String[]{"red", "black", "blue", "green", "yellow"};
        int randomColorIndex = randomGenerator2.nextInt(colors.length);
        randomColor = new Paint();
        randomColor.setColor(Color.parseColor(colors[randomColorIndex]));
        randomColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle(rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
        newRectangle.setColor(randomColor);
        rectangles.add(newRectangle);
        redRect.set(randomLeft, y, randomLeft + rectangleWidth, y + rectangleHeight);
        rects.add(redRect);
        canvas.drawRect(redRect, randomColor);
    }
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: `application stops when using timer` because calling `invalidate();` from non UI Thread

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way that I can use to make it refresh slower? cuz when I use invalidate alone, it refreshes very fast.

Comment: Ok, try to use `this.postdelayed` probably work as you want.

Comment: thanks!! it worked!!